# Adding Join after Union all

Tags: sql, join, union-all

Total Newbie to SQL,
I have two queries that I want to join:

```
source  /s/mysdrive/6298.hql;
set hivevar:selected_month= "2021-01";
set hivevar:selected_day=TO_DATE("2021-01-01");




SELECT CANADA.car_id,
"CANADA" as Source,
CANADA.tire_type,               
CANADA.km_traveled,         
CANADA.outside_temp,    
CANADA.cabin_temp,                      
CANADA.lights_on
FROM ctbls.can_data_na CANADA
WHERE CANADA.car_id in (${ID_LIST}) and CANADA.cvdc62_partition_month_x >= ${selected_month}

UNION ALL

SELECT UAE.car_id,
"UAE" as Source,
UAE.tire_type,              
UAE.km_traveled,            
UAE.outside_temp,       
UAE.cabin_temp,                     
UAE.lights_on
FROM ctbls.uae_data_me UAE
WHERE UAE.car_id in(${ID_LIST}) and UAE.cvdc62_partition_month_x >= ${selected_month}

UNION ALL

SELECT USA.car_id,
"USA" as Source,
USA.tire_type,              
USA.km_traveled,            
USA.outside_temp,       
USA.cabin_temp,                     
USA.lights_on
FROM ctbls.usa_data_na USA
WHERE USA.car_id in(${ID_LIST}) and USA.cvdc62_partition_date_x >= ${selected_day};
```

I want o join it to another query where ID = car_id from the previous query

```
select CARDim.ID,
CARDim.edition,
CARDim.sale_date,
CARDim.sale_country,
CARDim.model_year,
CARDim.test_date,
CARDim.test_type, 
CARDim.executed_by,
CARDim.pass_comm,
CARDim.techni_comm,
CARDim.customer,
CARDim.return
from test_db.car_dimension CARDim
where ID IN (${ID_LIST})
```

I think this can be done with a join but im not sure how the syntax should work for this one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! It sounds like this is your first `join`. Try practicing with a simpler query first. Review some simple examples in your documentation, e.g. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-join.html Once you understand a simpler example, it will become clear how to apply a `join` in your larger query.

Comment: You can read this and follow further links on the left panel to know how to use joins: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. You need to find a foreign key to relate the tables you want to join and then use the syntax explained on the link I mentioned.